Changing the WS-URL of React.js DEV
I have a React application running on PORT 5447, but it is redirected to a subdomain on port 80 using Nginx Multihost.
Example: dev.react-app.net
The connection basically works, but my React application cannot connect to the WS for live updates.
It connects automatically, I think because of the PORT specification in the React scripts in the package.json, to wss://dev.react-app.net:5447/ws.
But it should connect to wss://dev.react-app.net/ws.
I have tried to customize the URL somehow, but I have not succeeded.
I hope anybody can help me :d
